# onPageFinished not executing. "Method does not overwrite the Method in the superclass"

Tags: android, android-webview

My `onPageFinished` is not firing. At the @OverRide the warning "`Method does not overwrite the Method in the superclass`".

I have pasted the relevant code. Help willbe deeply appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    private String typeOrientation = "landscape";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (typeOrientation.equals("landscape"))
            {         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
       /* mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());*/
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            mWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onPageFinished` is not part of `WebChromeClient`, therefore you can't override it. It belongs to `WebViewClient`. You can set an instance of it calling `setWebViewClient`. You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html). Please be also aware that the correct signature is

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
```

with `public` as access specifier.

Comment: Now I get the error: onPageFinished(WebView,String) in <anonymous com.example.....MainActivity$1> cannot override onPageFinished(WebView,String) in WebViewClient
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public'

Comment: I edited my answer. You are missing `public` before `void`

Answer (score 1):

You used wrong method. Change to `setWebViewClient()`:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {}
    });
```

Comment: Now I get the error 'Error:(62, 18) error: onPageFinished(WebView,String) in <anonymous com.example.....MainActivity$1> cannot override onPageFinished(WebView,String) in WebViewClient
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public'

Comment: Nearly correct. missed the public infront of void :)